# Does NativeSearchQueryBuilder support script fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Am trying to write the below elastic query using spring data with NativeSearchQueryBuilder

```
 "script_fields" : {
            "test1" : {
                "script" : "(doc['field'].value * 1.05)"
            }
        }
```

I don't see any option to add script fields there. Am I missing something? or there is another way to add the script fields to the query?